# android WebView goBackOrForward() vs goBack()

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView and i using WebView.goBack() when tap back button and i using WebView.goBackOrForward(x) in another place.

My question is that why WebView.goBackOrForward(x) loads visited web page again from internet but WebView.goBack() does not load visited web page again and shows previous web page quickly?

Answer (score 1):

As in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html):

```
goBack
Added in API level 1
void goBack ()
Goes back in the history of this WebView.
```

instead

```
goBackOrForward
Added in API level 1
void goBackOrForward (int steps)
Goes to the history item that is the number of steps away from the current item. Steps is negative if backward and positive if forward.
```

I assume that knowing exactly which page WebView is going to load make it faster as with `goBack` it always load the previous page. `goBackOrForward` need to calculate which page it need to load before loading it. I'm not sure about that, you should check the code.